# Create different regular expression based on selection on a form

Tags: regex, forms

Currently I'm making the payment form of my project. Now I'm creating the regular expression based on the selection on a form. Below is the code of the payment form

```
<h1>Payment </h1>
<fieldset>
<legend> 
    <font size="6">Please input your payment information correctly</font>
</legend>
<p>
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Your Reservation Number: <?php echo $reservation_id;?><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="reservation_id" value="<?php echo $reservation_id;?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="roomtype" value="<?php echo $roomtype;?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="num_of_rooms" value="<?php echo $num_of_rooms;?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="dor" value="<?php echo $dor;?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="dco" value="<?php echo $dco;?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="length_of_stay" value="<?php echo $length_of_stay;?>">
        </li>
        <li>
            Bank in From: <br>
            <select name="bank_in_from" id="bank_in_from">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="Bank A">Bank A</option>
            <option value="Bank B">Bank B</option>
            <option value="Bank C">Bank C</option>

          </select>
        </li>
        <li>
            Account No.: <br>
            <input type="text" name="acc_no">
        </li>
        <li>
            Holder Name: <br>
            <input type="text" name="holder_name">
        </li>



          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <input type="reset" value="Clear" >
        <li>

    </ul>
```

The cases are like this

- if user choose Bank A, the `acc no.` form is acceptable if the number of digit is not less than or more than 12
- if user choose Bank B, the `acc no.` form is acceptable if the number of digit is not less than or more than 10
- if user choose Bank C, the `acc no.` form is acceptable if the number of digit is not less than or more than 9

All account numbers are obviously numbers, not mixed with letters or any special characters.

how's the code looks like?

Answer (score 0):

A surprisingly straightforward way to handle this would be to use a variable to represent the different regex pattern you wished to use.

Thus something along the lines of:

```
switch($chosen_bank){
        case('bankA'):
             $appropriate_regex = '\d{12}';
             break;
        case('bankB'):
             $appropriate_regex = '\d{10}';
             break;
        case('bankC'):
             $appropriate_regex = '\d{9}';
             break;
 }

 // then you'll need something like:

 $submitted_string = $_POST['submitted_bank_number'];
 $pattern = "/$appropriate_regex/";
 preg_match($pattern, $submitted_string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
 print_r($matches);
```

That will output:

```
   Array
   (
       [0] => Array
           (
               [0] => 1234563820
           )

   )
```

So you can grab the bank account number using

```
   $target_bank_number = $matches[0][0];
```

and you should be able to take it from there.

As far as getting hold of those variables in the first place, you can see a basic form processing example at [Calculating values with formulae from user input in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747922/calculating-values-with-formulae-from-user-input-in-php/22748799#22748799)

As you have specified action="" in your form tag, you would include something like the following lower down your page to handle user submissions:

```
<?php

    if ($_POST){
          $php_varA    = $_POST['submitted_form_valueA'];
          $chosen_bank = $_POST['chosen_bank'];

          //here process the input using regular expressions/ database access, etc, etc

    }     

?>
```

?>